# How to save slickgrid data to "data" array on click of some external button?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

When we change the value in any cell in sickgrid, that value is not stored to the "data" array until focus is removed from the cell. How can we make this data in the edit field of any cell to be stored in "data" array on click of some button outside of the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#save").click(function(){
     grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
})
```

Not tested, but i think it should do the trick.